# Nginx git server authorization only for pushing

Tags: nginx, git

I deployed a nginx git server and want to request authorization only for pushing. Tried a lot of solutions, none worked for me.
Here is my server configuration

```
server {


        root /var/www/mysite;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


server {


        root /var/www/git;

    error_log /var/www/git/gitservererror.log;
    access_log /var/www/git/gitserveraccess.log;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name git.mysite.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

location ~ /git(/.*) {
    
    # fcgiwrap is set up to listen on this host:port
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        # export all repositories under GIT_PROJECT_ROOT
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /var/www/git;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO           $1;
}



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.cassioavila.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.cassioavila.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = www.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;

        server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}


server {
    if ($host = git.mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name git.mysite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I changed the real site name for mysite.com.
I tried using regex, but i'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: I don't see anything in your configuration related to authorization.

Comment: as i said, i tried making possible cloning the repo not needing authorization, but i did not manage to get it working, so i disabled authorization